# is there any difference between work om Office 2007 and 2003 in C#

Tags: c#

i work with Office 2007 (excell) in my C# program.

i do this reference: `Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library`

it work excellent !, but if in the computer there is Office 2003

is it work good ? if not, what i need to do ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to do late binding for it to work with multiple versions of office.
Here's some VB.Net code I had laying around but it should show you the difference between late and early binding at least.

```
Dim objWordApplication As Object
try
    objWordApplication = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Catch ex As Exception
    If Err.Number = 429 Then '429 means Word is not running
        objWordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")    'start a new instance
    End If
End Try
Dim objWordDocument As Object = objWordApplication.Documents.Add("docname.doc")
```